# Ошибка при загрузке d'n'd

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var upload = function(files) {
    var formData = new FormData(),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    x = 0;

    for(x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
        formData.append('file[]', files[x]);
    }
    console.log(x);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        displayUploads(data);
    };

    xhr.open('post', 'upload.php');
    xhr.send(formData);
};
```

> **Uncaught SyntaxError**: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>   at JSON.parse ()
>   at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (строка 55, там где x = 0)

Это возникает при загрузке больше 20 файлов

Answer (score 0):

Вам вместо json с сервера приходит html (по всей видимости с текстом какой то ошибки)
Проверьте, что конкретно приходит в ответе, с помощью вкладки Network в консоли браузера, либо с помощью такой конструкции:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    try{
       var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       displayUploads(data);
    }catch(e){
       console.error('Invalid JSON!', this.responseText);
       // Тут можно обработать ошибку
    }
};
```

Comment: Пишет, что скрипт загрузки, который был вызван xhr.onload() был отменен (canceled) и размер равен 0

Comment: @NNP Попробуйте добавить try catch из моего ответа, и посмотрите что в консоли выведет

Comment: Сейчас в консоли вообще перестало выводить ошибки, хоть через console.error(), хоть через console.log(), [скрин](http://imgur.com/a/7kqFe)

Comment: Подправил, сейчас выводит ошибку, что максимальное количество отправляемых файлов было превышено

Comment: @NNP Ну всё, на клиенте у вас значит всё ок) Дальнейшие вопросы - к серверу. Можно реализовать логику отправки файлов отдельными пачками, чтобы обойти это ограничение. (т.е разбивать массив файлов на куски нужного размера и отсылать в несколько запросов)